# HTTPs Request Works on Postman but not Android app

Tags: android, https, authorization, postman

I'm developing an android app that uses Asynchttpclient to make GET https request to an API (not controlled by me), but I'm getting authorization error.
So, I've tried to use Postman mac os x app to make the same GET https request (same parameters and headers) and the request manage to get expected response without authorization error.
What could be different between the https request of android app and Postman that caused the authorization error?

Thanks!

Comment: Need to provide more info around the API call and error

Comment: problem solved! ended up that the header info that i sent from Postman and android app wasn't exactly the same. correcting the header info fixed the problem.

Comment: Can u then close this question or delete if u think so